# Font Awesome Icons Behave Like Schrödinger's Cat on Mobile

Tags: font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome 5 Free via a kit.  On desktop, the icons work perfectly.  But on mobile (iOS chrome (normal and incognito), iOS firefox focus, iOS safari), they behave like Schrödinger's cats...

On first page load, the icons appear.  Tap reload and they disappear and are replaced by small squares.  Tap reload ***again*** and they ***re***appear.  Every ***other*** tap of reload shows or hides the icons.

I notice the same behavior if I toggle back and forth between "request desktop site" and "request mobile site".  (I'm not sure what's really going on under the hood there since the page renders the same either way.)

Since they do appear correctly, at least part of the time, I don't think it's a cross-origin problem or a caching problem.

An example page is here: https://onlinesafetyzone.com/learn/learning-zone.php

I've read many posts, here and on GitHub and none of the solutions has worked.  Anyone have a clue what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have somekind of a XSS issue. I would try to download the fontawsome resources and deploy them with the application. Can be that they have a CDN problem, every second time the fonts break :| so maybe one of the nodes is flipping.

Comment: Yup, downloading and referencing the resources locally seems to have worked.  But what kind of XSS issue would cause the problem?  If everything "works" one time (and 2 refreshes later) why would they work all the time?  Even if they're doing some kind of load balancing, it seems quite coincidental that I'd "perfectly" flip back and forth between their nodes.

Comment: You should be the security profs here :) A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. is just a warning, so i guess if ever the problem can be caused by the jquery error.  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function...

Comment: That's weird.  I'm not including any ads or trackers on the web site (and certainly nothing from doubleclick.net).  The only cookies I see are from Cloudflare (CDN), Google Analytics, and ConvertKit (forms).